# wxWidgets on Windows: How to create wxCursor from the application resource number?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am rewriting the application using wxWidges (native C++). I do have several user-defined mouse cursors created via the Visual Studio resource editor. The resource editor creates for each one the file like MYCURSOR.CUR with the bitmap and the other info, adds one entry to the `app.rc` file like:

```
IDC_MYCURSOR      CURSOR     "MYCURSOR.CUR"
```

... and adds one line to the generated `resource.h` like:

```
#define  IDC_MYCURSOR 103
```

When the application is compiled, the compiled resources take the binary form that becomes integral part of the `app.exe`. When the wxWidgets framework is not used, one can call:

```
HCURSOR hCur = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYCURSOR));
```

where `hInstance` is the handle to the application that has the executable with the cursor resource (in compiled binary form, here inside the `app.exe`).

With wxWidgets, I can create the instance of the `wxCursor` class, and pass it the name of the file with the cursor -- like `wxCursor cursor(wxT("MYCURSOR.CUR"));` -- and it works. However, the `MYCURSOR.CUR` file must be found (say placed in the same directory as the `app.exe`). In other words, it ignores the compiled resource attached to the `app.exe`. If the file of the name is not found, the cursor shape is not loaded.

Is there any way that--in Windows--would allow me to load the cursor from the resource, based on the resource number?

I understand, that the code should be written the way that is portable say to a Unix-based OS. Is there any recommended way to transform the Windows resource or the `MYCURSOR.CUR` file to the form that is compiled to or attached to the produced executable?

**UPDATE**

I have found at wxWidget discussion forum the hint in [wxCursor from .rc [Win]](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1426&p=5967&hilit=wxcursor%20windows%20resource#p5967) by upCASE (April 2005):

```
wxCursor( "#1", wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR_RESOURCE );
```

I tried to use it with my number and it seems to work, but I do not know why. Then I improved it like this:

```
#define STR(value) #value
#define RES(value) wxT("#") wxT(STR(value))
...
wxCursor cur(RES(IDC_MYCURSOR), wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR_RESOURCE);
```

I consider that uggly and likely not to be the right way. Anyway, can you explain that?

Also, looking inside the `c:\wxWidgets-2.9.4\src\msw\cursor.cpp`, I have found that the constructor that takes the string argument interprets it as a filename (at least the argument is named `filename`). The code...

```
switch ( kind )
{
    case wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR_RESOURCE:
        hcursor = ::LoadCursor(wxGetInstance(), filename.t_str());
        break;
...
```

suggests that the `LoadCursor()` is used the way that is not used for the stack Windows cursor (otherwise the first argument should be NULL). The `::LoadCursor` names the argument as `LPCTSTR lpCursorName`, and [the doc says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that

> The name of the cursor resource to be loaded. Alternatively, this parameter can consist of the resource identifier in the low-order word and zero in the high-order word. The MAKEINTRESOURCE macro can also be used to create this value.

I tried also the

```
wxCursor cur(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYCURSOR), wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR_RESOURCE);
```

but it fails because the `wxCursor` constructor applies the string conversion -- see the above `filename.t_str()`. Can you comment on this?

**SOLVED** (plus some explanation what I was confronted with...)

Earlier, I have worked with Windows application resources only via IDE, or I did only small things directly via an `app.rc` file. When digging deeper with the help of the [VZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12704183/1346705) and the [ravenspoint answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696948/1346705), I may understand better what they initially meant and what Microsoft did in the past and later, and what was the source of my confusion.

Firstly, when you create some resource (say mouse cursor) via Visual Studio IDE, it is automatically given a *numeric identification* (say `103`). The number is automatically captured in `resource.h` as `#define IDC_MYCURSOR 103` -- i.e. given also the macro identifier. The macro identifier is used when the information about the cursor is inserted to the `app.rc`, like this:

```
IDC_MYCURSOR      CURSOR     "MYCURSOR.CUR"
```

As the `resource.h` is included into the `app.rc`, it is probably roughly equivalent to

```
103               CURSOR     "MYCURSOR.CUR"
```

and the resource compiler probably converts the `103` number to `#103` string or something like that. Probably because of that, the `wxCursor("#103", wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR_RESOURCE);` works. The indirection of the `103` via the `resource.h` was the source of my confusion when trying to understand ravenspoint's point :)

However, the usage of an `app.rc` without the `resource.h` and the string identifier of the resource was probably the initial intention of the designers. Thus, writing

```
mycursor          CURSOR     "MYCURSOR.CUR"
```

means that the resource-script-file compiler creates the `"mycursor"` string identifier that can be used directly inside the `LoadCursor()` function or the `wxCursor("mycursor", ...);`. This is the way recommended by VZ and found in the pointed out wx samples.

I have created my own `cursor.rc2` that contains mouse-cursor resource information. The `.rc2` is then included into the `app.rc` file to be combined with the other resource information... and it works! :) The summary is: *Do not use numbers for identification of the resources. Use strings.*

Thanks again for your time and experience,
   Petr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a numeric ID you need to use a not really obvious `wxCursor("103")`. This is why with wxWidgets you'd typically use string names (like `my_cursor` in the answer above).

Of course, you can also do

```
#include <wx/cpp.h>

wxCursor cursor(wxSTRINGIZE(IDC_CURSOR));
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadim! (Just posted the update with blind moves towards the smimilar.) So, the extra # is unneccessary. I am at the very beginning of the application rewrite process, and I would like to rewrite it nicely from the beginnint. Then... Is there any article with hints like that "what to do when rewriting using the already existing `resource.h`"? Should I use the `wxSTRINGIZE` the way you show, or should I manually stringize the `resource.h` to avoid using the `wxSTRINGIZE`? Will the resource compiler be happy if the `my_cursor` in `my_cursor CURSOR "mycursor.cur"` be a string?

Comment: Just tried, but the `#` must be used in front of the stringized number (like `wxCursor cur("#" wxSTRINGIZE(IDC_CURSOR));`. Otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right, the string form of an integer resource is indeed "#103", sorry for forgetting about this "#". You probably should define your own macro `#define MAKE_IDC(name) "#" wxSTRINGIZE(IDC_ ## name)` (I've moved "IDC_" prefix out just to avoid repeating it) if you do it like this. Otherwise you can indeed just use "my_cursor" as is in the .rc file and then simply use it as a string in wxCursor ctor. Unless you have a lot of cursors (and/or bitmaps, icons, ...) to change, I'd do it like this.

Comment: At VZ and @ravenspoint: It seems that the resource identifier cannot be a string -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5f4bses.aspx. Then, the "#103" (via the nice macro) seems to be the only way to make it working. Can you comment on that? Is the # related to the nature of the Windows kernel or is it interpreted by wxWidgets?

Comment: I don't know how to explain this MSDN page but you definitely can use strings for resource identifiers. Open any wxWidgets sample in the resource editor and you will see that cursors are called "WXCURSOR_BLANK" and so on in the ''compiled'' resource file. Also, check `LoadCursor()` documentation in MSDN, its second parameter is a string, not a number, and a number can be actually passed in it only using the horrible `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` hack.

Comment: Thanks again. I have finally tried more and it works just fine. I am going to update the question to summarize my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

In the resource file

```
my_cursor CURSOR "mycursor.cur"
```

In the code

```
wxCursor(my_cursor)
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow, but I doubt. The reason is that the `my_cursor` is the macro name for the integer value. There is nothing that would convert `"my_cursor"` string to the `my_cursor` integer (called `IDC_MYCURSOR` in the question).

Comment: It does not work either. The reason is that it leads to `void wxCursor::InitFromStock(wxStockCursor idCursor)` and it accepts only stock cursors as `wxCURSOR_HAND` and the like. The `InitFromStock` defines inside the static structure `StdCursor` with the initialized array of standard cursors. The number is used as index to the array. When out of range, the `invalid cursor id in wxCursor() ctor` is reported.

Comment: Thanks once more. I have finally dig deep enough to the resources. I am going to update the question to summarize my experience.